# What is the relationship between iTunes Library.itl and iTunes Music Library.xml?

Tags: itunes

I know that iTunes keeps its information in the itl file, so what's the point of having the itunes Music Library.xml file?  Is there any way to get itunes to re-create the music library from the xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .itl keeps your entire library, the xml keeps some components of it so that other applications can make use of your library. Since XML is a widely used standard, they chose to use it instead of using custom proprietary calls to the .itl file.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1660

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to recreate your music library from the xml file.

If you delete the content of the .itl file using Notepad, iTunes will see it as corrupt the next time you start the program.  It will then use the xml file to recreate its .itl file.

Comment: That's quite true! I tested this to try to rebuild the ITL database from the XML, so that iTunes would assume EDITED file paths on the XML... The ITL file was rebuilded, and so was the XML!!! iTunes is a headache! I just wanted it to assume the XML configuration :-\

Comment: I can vouch that this still works in 2020.  Moved my library to a different drive, did a mass copy/replace in the XML file, and "corrupted" the .itl file using the same technique... a few minutes later, I had my library restored, complete with playlists and ratings.